# Closure of Subset of Metric Space by Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

If $M$ is a metric space and $C\subset M,$ a proof of the statement $x\in cl(C) \iff$ there exists a sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$ in $C$ which converges to $x$ is given here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Subset_of_Metric_Space_by_Convergent_Sequence

In the proof of the necessary condition, the following statement is given:
"Since $\forall n: x_n \in C$, it follows that $\forall \epsilon > 0: B_\epsilon(x)\cap C \neq \emptyset$. Hence $x\in cl(C)$."

How does $x\in cl(C)$ follow from $\forall \epsilon > 0: B_\epsilon(x)\cap C \neq \emptyset$? This doesn't seem to immediately fall out from any definitions of closure that I have seen.

EDIT: This actually seems to have been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068999/metric-spaces-closure-of-a-set-is-the-set-of-all-limits-of-sequences-in-that-se?rq=1). However, it does not discuss the equivalence of definitions between the set of adherence points and union of a set with its limit points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in C$, then there is nothing to prove. Now assume that $x\notin C$. So for any open set $G$ that containing $x$, find some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq G$. Now $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap C\ne\emptyset$, say, $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap C$, then $y\in C$, in particular, $y\ne x$, so $G\cap C-\{x\}\ne\emptyset$, this proves that $x$ is an accumulation point of $C$, so $x\in\overline{C}$.

Here I use the property that $\overline{C}=C\cup C'$, where $C'$ is the set of all accumulation points of $C$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense - thank you! So, the fact that $x\not \in C \implies$ $x$ is an accumulation point of $C$ is given by the fact that there is a sequence in $C$ which converges to $x$?

Comment: Yes, that goes through as well.

Comment: What are you doing in the second line? How do we know that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap C \neq \emptyset$? What if $G$ and $C$ were disjoint?

Comment: Because $x\in C'$.

Comment: The very first step is to assumed that $x\in\overline{C}$, this is enough to guarantee that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap C\ne\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is not an element of the closure of $C$ then it is an element of the complement of the closure of $C$ which is an open set. Then $\epsilon >0$ can be found such that $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a subset of this complement so that  $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap C\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap\text{cl}(C)=\varnothing$.